# Ruby (rack/passenger app) returns httpd/unix-directory content type instead of text/html

Tags: ruby, apache, unix, passenger

I am new at Ruby development. I have a simple ruby app powered by Passenger on Apache. My source looks something like this

```
class Demo
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    text = req.params['text']
    Rack::Response.new.finish do |res|
      res['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      res.status = 200
      res.write text
    end
  end
end

run Demo.new
```

Even though the content type is set to text/html. I noticed the http header returned is httpd/unix-directory. Here is what the headers look like.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 18:51:29 GMT
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.37
Status: 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: httpd/unix-directory
```

If I don't access through the Apache/Passenger vhost but run `rackup config.ru` directly from the console and access via `:9292`, everything seems ok.

Why is this so? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1197) this might be an issue with apache configuration of `mod_mime`:

> Apache's mod_mime sets Content-Type to httpd/x-unix-directory whenever it notices that the current URL maps to a directory. Usually the web app overrides this Content-Type by providing its own Content-Type header, but node-env doesn't do that. The browser sees the httpd/x-unix-directory Content-Type and tries to download it.
>
> You can work around this by disabling mod_mime. I'll modify 4.0.45 to unset the httpd/x-unix-directory header.

Answer (score 0):

It is as Uri Agassi said. So you either need to modify your app to set a Content-Type header, or you need to upgrade to Phusion Passenger 4.0.45 or later.